# CORB Batch process output Report Extraction issue

Tags: linux, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-corb

While running the CORB job, I am  Extracting 100,000 URI's and loading the
data in one file at Linux server. The expectation is all the output records    should be store in one file with 100k count. However The data was stored in    multiple files with different counts. Can anyone help me out with root cause    why the CORB process is creating multiple files in the output directory?

Please find the details of the CORB properties file that I configured in my local directory

**Properties file :**

```
THREAD-COUNT=4
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.extension.ResilientTransform
SSL-CONFIG-CLASS=com.marklogic.developer.corb.TwoWaySSLConfig
SSL-PROPERTIES-FILE=/eiestore/ssl-configs/common-corb-sslconfig.properties
DECRYPTER=com.marklogic.developer.corb.HostKeyDecrypter
MODULE-ROOT=/a/abcmodules/corb-process/
MODULES-DATABASE="abcmodules"
URIS-MODULE=corb-select-uris.xqy
XQUERY-MODULE=corb-get-process.xqy
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
PRE-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PreBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-TOP-CONTENT=Id,value,type
EXPORT-FILE-DIR=/a/b/c/d/
```

---

Comment: I don't see EXPORT-FILE-NAME or URIS_BATCH_REF. If neither are set, then ExportBatchToFileTask should throw a NullPointerException. However, you have two PROCESS-TASK properties configured. CORB currently only runs one PROCESS-TASK. Could it be that your ResilientTransform is writing out these multiple files? Post the code for your ResilientTransform and we might be able to identify how/why. You might want to have that class extend ExportBatchToFileTask and only configure one PROCESS-TASK.